# Where can I set the tomcat configuration sendReasonPhrase = true in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

What all am I trying is to send `HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST` instead of `HTTP/1.1 400` to the client side. To do this I need to set the tomcat configuration `sendResponsePhrase` as true.

But I could not find any configuration in application.properties to set this up.

I tried something like `server.tomcat.sendReasonPhrase`, but it shows as an invalid configuration over there

I am using tomcat version 8

Comment: Have you tried `server.sendReasonPhrase` without the `tomcat`? Also, just FYI, the docs say: `This option is deprecated and will be removed in Tomcat 9. The reason phrase will not be sent.`

Comment: @mumpitz yeah i have tried server.sendReasonPhrase, but it still shows as an invalid configuration

Comment: Well then maybe you **are** using Tomcat 9+ and this config parameter **actually is** deprecated and removed from your Tomcat version?

Comment: If you are using the Tomcat version lesser than 9.0.X, then you can configure sendReasonPhrase true or false in the Server.xml file as mentioned below.

 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" sendReasonPhrase="true" />